# 2005 Suzuki gsxr 750

Tags: motorcycle, manual-transmission, suzuki, gsxr

I just bought a 05 gsxr750 it has 6k miles on it. I recently did a fresh oil change new air filter new spark plugs and tightened up the chain and lubed. I have had no problems running it until last night on my way home from work. It was feeling jerky and had a loss of acceleration for a couple seconds then it would go back to normal and keeps going on and on. I let the bike cool down and I rode it again. It seems to be only doing it when the engine is hot. I’m thinking it could be the coil packs going bad but I’m not sure. I put carb cleaner in it also. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Does your bike has a auto tune cycle?